# virtualenv ImportError: No module named _struct

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

I am trying to run virtualenv on fedora. I get the following output.

in the same session I did PYTHONHOME=/usr/bin/python2.7 and PYTHONPATH=/lib/python2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 16, in <module>
    import base64
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.py", line 9, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
```

Comment: `_struct` is part of the Python standard library. I suspect there is a problem with your system's Python installation. maybe try `yum reinstall python python-support`

Comment: I'm also facing this issue after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04LTS. re-installing python doesn't work as everytime it install with the same error!

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it is somehow related to an environment-issue; it happens in a chrooted environment for me, but not in my larger "main" environment, so I assume python may check for something, perhaps fails to find it or can not proceed, then errors out with the above error. A bit annoying that this error-reporting is so weak for python.